# How can I have the delete key remove newline characters in normal mode (like delete in insert mode)?

Tags: key-bindings

My question is similar to [this one](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/20552/backspace-functionality-in-normal-mode) but for the `i_<Del>`.

In insert mode, if I type `<Del>` it removes the next character, including newlines. In normal mode, I have to type `x` if the cursor is inner the line or `J` if the cursor is just before the new line.

I could write a mapping that check the position of the cursor (something like `nmap <expr> <Del> getpos(".") == getpos("$") ? "J" : "x"`), but I am surprised there is no standard way to do that.

Comment: You can type `J` anywhere in the line...

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure this answers your question, but you can join the lines from anywhere in the line by simply pressing `J`:

```
                            *J*
J           Join [count] lines, with a minimum of two lines.
            Remove the indent and insert up to two spaces (see
            below).  Fails when on the last line of the buffer.
            If [count] is too big it is reduced to the number of
            lines available.
```

You might also be interested in any of the following nearby help topics:

- `v_J`
- `gJ` (and `v_gJ`)
- `:join`